# BigChaindb + Ethereum

Tags: scalability, database

In BigChaindb [paper](https://www.bigchaindb.com/whitepaper/bigchaindb-whitepaper.pdf), it's mentioned that it's compatible with Ethereum and is complementary to Ethereum. But BigChaindb has has its own consensus.

Question 1: How can BigChaindb work with Ethereum (smart contract)?

Question 2: Why would it improve scalability if we use it with Ethereum?

Comment: Duplicate https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1256/what-is-bigchaindb-and-how-can-it-be-used-with-ethereum