# What is the difference between IPDB and Blockchain Databases?

Tags: blockchain, private-blockchain, ipfs, database

I wanted to know what are the differences between IPFS, interplanetary file system and a block chain database like IPDB and BigChainDB

Comment: Related: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1256/what-is-bigchaindb-and-how-can-it-be-used-with-ethereum

Comment: Looks like BigChainDB is stored as a decentralized MongoDB database and can be queried as such.  Storing files in this way has [more overhead](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-model-operations/#storage-optimization-for-small-documents) than strictly necessary, but that overhead keeps track of relationships which can improve performance (e.g. when searching your files).  There may be some projects already trying to build something similar on top of IPFS (e.g. looks like [AvionDB](https://simpleaswater.com/intro-to-aviondb/) is doing just this).

Answer (score 1):

IPFS is a cache layer. It does not guarantee the storage of the content. It is just a way to address and cache online content. Think it as a more web browser friendly BitTorrent.

BigChainDB is a SQL-like database where clients can sign the transaction and they can be guaranteed to come from a certain key holder. A super admin cannot manipulate the data without leaving a trace. BigchainDB does not have any kind of economic guarantees that the system keeps running, you still need to have a sysadmin and pay servers.

Public blockchains have some sort of economic and reward mechanism, which incentives block producing and thus guarantees persistence, immutability and other features of the chain. Having those guarantees makes it suitable as a transfer-of-value and store-of-value network, which the two options above are not.

Comment: To add some specificity, [BigChainDB uses MongoDB](https://bigchaindb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/query.html), a NoSQL style database.